# Alternative to world/terrain editing with jmonkey

Tags: java, jmonkeyengine, world-editor

I have been studying Java for almost a year and have been trying to develop a game using jMonkey. I have tried Unity before but since I only know Java I decided to go with jMonkey.

My problem is that the terrain/world edit in jMonkey is buggy. When I make changes to the terrain I sometimes can not save. Many others seem to have the same problem too.

I would also prefer drag n drog exactly like Unity has, but jMonkey doesn't seem to have that.

Is there any other way I can create the terrain/world (with drag n drop like Unity) and then import into jMonkey? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following:

1. [jME3 SpaceShift Editor](https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/jme3-spaceshift-editor/35179)
2. [World Machine](http://www.world-machine.com/)
3. [Blender.org](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Textures/Maps/Creating_a_Heightmap_from_a_Plane)

But you could also look into the [List of level editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_level_editors) you probably would need to create an importer or do some magic with your output files but it is very possible.

Comment: I dont understand the down vote jME3 SpaceShift Editor would be the closest thing to Unity3D the community has to here is a a video of it in action https://youtu.be/d-7HdPSl1BE

Comment: jME3 SpaceShift Editor really looks good, thanks for the answer!